# UIBarButtonItem black instead of white

Tags: iphone, image, uibutton

I have that Navigation Controller and I'm adding 1 button by code this way:

```
UIBarButtonItem *configButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"config.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showConfigWindow)]; 
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = configButton;
```

It's working right but the icons are black instead of white!!

If I use this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *configButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showConfigWindow)];
```

The text is showed properly in white.

The icons are ok cause I'm using them through interface builder and they show right.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of what's happening?  Are you sure your image is in the correct format and didn't get inversed, for some reason?  (Try another color and see what happens)

Comment: Have a look here: http://personales.upv.es/jorfermo/screenshot.jpg
It's the same image in an UIButton. The one up is on the navigation controller and the down one is over a uitoolbar.

Answer (score 0):

`UIBarButtonItem` renders images in grayscale according to the images alpha value. So, if your image is fully opaque, then it will always render black, no matter what color the source image is, but if your image is transparent, it will render some shade of grey.

In order to render it fully white, or a color, you need to create a custom `UIBarButtonItem`. See [Can I have a UIBarButtonItem with a colored image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835260/can-i-have-a-uibarbuttonitem-with-a-colored-image) for details