# UIBarButtonItem Image is not shown and instead a white rectangle in the size of image is shown, Why?

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

With whatever image I try to intialize the UIBarButtonItem, its just showing a white background in the size of the image. Even when I tired in interface builder, the result is the same. All these images when used with other objects works perfectly.

How can I solve this??

Comment: Difficult to tell without seeing your code or IB setup

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Only alpha values in the image are used to create the bar button image. Whatever image you provide is converted into a image with shades of white, based on the alpha values.

So given that your image is completely white it is clear you don't have any transparency.

The [guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1) have this to say:

> - Use the PNG format.
> - Use pure white with appropriate alpha.
> - Do not include a drop shadow.
> - Use anti-aliasing.
> - If you decide to add a bevel, be sure that it is 90° (to help you do
>     this, imagine a light source
>     positioned at the top of the icon).
> - For toolbar and navigation bar icons, create an icon that measures
>     about 20 x 20 pixels.
> - For tab bar icons, create an icon that measures about 30 x 30 pixels.
>
> Note: The icon you provide for
>   toolbars, navigation bars, and tab
>   bars is used as a mask to create the
>   icon you see in your application. It
>   is not necessary to create a
>   full-color icon.

**You can however use a custom view** to get a full-colour image as this question shows:

[Can I have a UIBarButtonItem with a colored image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835260/can-i-have-a-uibarbuttonitem-with-a-colored-image)

This is a bit over the top though and it would be best to stick to the guidelines and use a normal button with an appropriately formatted image.

Answer (score 17):

In ios 7 onwards this will help

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(YOUR_METHOD:)];
```

Answer (score 13):

In Swift 3 
I found that the following works - here shown as an array of more than one barButtonItem

```
  let barButtonItem1    = UIBarButtonItem( image: UIImage(named: "myImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal) , style: .plain ,target: self, action: #selector(yourAction))
  let barButtonItem2    = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "myImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)  , style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(yourAction))

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [barButtonItem1, barButtonItem2]
```

This shows x2 barButtons on the rightHandSide. 
To shown the left simply change to

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [barButtonItem1, barButtonItem2]