# How to have two line of UIBarButtons in aUIToolBar

Tags: iphone, ios

Can any one tell me, is it possible to have two lines of UIBarButtons in a UIToolBar ? Like assume there are 8 buttons, and four button in each line in a UIToolBar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you need to go customization way.

Comment: Thanks Adil. But How to approach any idea..

Comment: Amit, you can add custom buttons to toolbar, have a look at [How to customize the UIToolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4666726/593709)